# MYSQL - Multiple all data in 1 column with max value in the same column

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, sql

I have data in criteria table like this:

```
+----+
| c1 |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
+----+
```

all I want is to multiply all the data in c1 with the highest value in column c1, so it becomes:

```
1x5
2x5
3x5
4x5
5x5
```

And the result should like this:

```
+--------+
| new c1 |
+--------+
| 5      |
| 10     |
| 15     |
| 20     |
| 25     |
+--------+
```

so, what query should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
SELECT t.m * c1 
FROM MyTable, 
(SELECT max(c1) as m from MyTable) t
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb6c4e/4)

Comment: thanks before, but it doesn't work on phpMyAdmin. Can you help me with another query maybe? @YCF_L

Comment: Your answer is work very well, I just need to update my phpmyadmin :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross join on subquery that calculate the max  value

```
 select a.c1*t.max_c1
 from my_table  a
 cross  join (
  select max(c1)  as max_c1
  from my_table 
 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT (xx.columnName * xx.max_val) AS 'expected_result' FROM (SELECT MAX(columnName) AS max_val,myTable.columnName FROM myTable)xx
```